# What happens when auth_key is revoked in PubNub?

Tags: websocket, pubnub

I'm weighing up different push/websocket providers and, in the case of PubNub, I'm wondering how a subscribed client will be notified when their auth key has been revoked. Using the JavaScript SDK, I'm assuming that the callback will be notified of this scenario? Ideally, I'd want my client to then go through the full grant cycle again when it realises it needs to obtain a new auth key, I just need to know what callback event to watch for. Will it be reported as an error?

Comment: A revoked `auth_key` will be denied access upon the next stream request.  You will see `403` access denied.  You can check the status flag in your SDK for the `auth_key` status.  Then you can generate a new `auth_key`.

Comment: Do you mean that an active subscription won't be terminated straight away?

Comment: The subscription will be terminated after the last message is received.  You have the option to send a "goodbye" message to the client with the expired `auth_key` with a reason.  1.) revoke auth_key then 2.) publish a goodbye message.